# How to undo strikethrough on Google documents

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I undo strikethrough on a whole page with table layout?

I have tried <kbd>Command key</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

- **shortcut for strikethrough is **<kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd></kbd>****

  > [image]
- **but sometimes you will need to do: **<kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd></kbd>** (depends on your selection)**

  > [image]

---

---

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Go to format and press clear formatting.